# Switch from Windows-1252 to utf8 default encoding in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing a module in Python using a Windows os. Unfortunately, the default enconding is cp1252 and it's giving me problems with special unicode characters (like the Hawaiian okina, **ʻ**, aka as '\u02bb'). 
I managed to solve the problem, but I would like to change the default setting.
I'm using Python 3.4.1. I read on other posts about the import sys and reload(sys) trick but it's not currently working for me.
Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the default setting in Windows?

Comment: Either in Windows or, locally, in Python.